# Swift: Shared Keychain returns nil in Widgets and WidgetIntent

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am attempting to share information (in this case, a refreshToken which I use to refresh a accessToken) between my app, a Widget Extension and a Widget Intent via a shared Keychain, but for some reason, the Keychain always return nil in the Widget and WidgetIntent.

I have checked that I have the following:

1. Enabled Keychain Sharing, and set the same keychain groups (ie com.mycompany.myapp)
2. Prefix the accessGroup with App ID (ie ABCDEFGHIJ.com.mycompany.myapp)

Code:

```
//In my Constants.swift
struct Constants {
    struct Keychain {
        static let KeychainAccessGroupKey = "ABCDEFGHIJ.com.mycompany.myapp"
        static let RefreshTokenKey = "refreshToken"
    }
}

//In widgets entry view
//Text always prints "no RF", meaning refreshToken in the keychain is nil
struct WidgetEntryView : View {

    var body: some View {
        let keychain = Keychain(accessGroup: Constants.Keychain.KeychainAccessGroupKey)
        let refreshToken = try? keychain.getString(Constants.Keychain.RefreshTokenKey)
        Text(refreshToken ?? "no RF") 
            .font(.caption)
        }
}

//In app, I implemented a button to pull the refreshToken, and it is not nil
ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button("All apps") {
                        let keychain = Keychain(accessGroup: Constants.Keychain.KeychainAccessGroupKey)
                        let refreshToken = try? keychain.getString(Constants.Keychain.RefreshTokenKey)
                        print("RF", refreshToken) // Not nil
                    }
                }
```

I use this [KeychainAccess](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess) library for my keychain implementation. I am always running on simulator, and the target OS is iOS14.

Where could I have gone wrong?